# How can I avoid request timeout error in django app hosted in a docker container?

Tags: django

I would like to create a button in django admin site that would run a process which could take a few minutes to complete. I have the app hosted in a docker container. It would be nice to receive a notification as well if the process was completed successfully or not.

Comment: What web server are you using to host your Django app? gunicorn? apache?

Comment: I am using gunicorn

Comment: You should really perform long running tasks on a worker node but if you have to do it on the main web thread, you can set the gunicorn timeout by following the instructions here: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout

Comment: Agree with the above, users aren't going to wait that long for a request to finish processing. This shouldn't be running inside the main request thread. Use something like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to delegate the task and have it not block the main thread. Then let the user check if the task is finished (e.g. with a javascript that regularly polls for some result).

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining it clearly. Users will not have access to this button. I have some files that need to be updated time to time. Instead of getting into the container and running the code manually, I would like to just press the button when I need to process the updates.